# Combining Fields in an array based upon value

Tags: php

So, I have looked at several posts regarding array_merge and array_unique, but haven't seen anything exactly like what I'm trying to do.  I'm assuming the solution would be something like this: [PHP - Merge-down multidimensional arrays by named key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748292/php-merge-down-multidimensional-arrays-by-named-key?rq=1), except that I'm using strings and I'm also going to wind up with duplicate keys which I assume is not going to work.

I have an array ($classagg) that I'm using to create a webpage detailing classes for an event.  The code I'm currently using is:

```
usort($classagg, function($a, $b) {
 return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
});

foreach($classagg as $out){
print "
<p>
<a class=\"education-class-list-title\" name=\"$out[presenter]\">$out[title]</a><br />
<span class=\"education-class-list-description\">$out[description]</span><br />
<span class=\"education-class-list-presenter\"> Presented by: <a           href=\"/event/$out[eventType]/$out[eid]?qt-event=3#$out[presenter]\">$out[presenter]</a>        </span>
</p>
";
}
```

Everything is working well, however I have some classes where two presenters are presenting the same class.  The system is setup as a CRM, so unfortunately I can't have a combined application for both presenters.

A simplified version of the current array might like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Class 1
            [description] => This is a Class
            [presenter] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Class 2
            [description] => This is a another class
            [presenter] => Sue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Class 1
            [description] => Sally is presenting with John
            [presenter] => Sally
        )


)
```

I want to merge arrays 0 and 2, keeping the title, keeping one of the descriptions (preferably the longer one), and keep both of the names.

I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();

foreach( $array as $class ) {
  if( isset( $newArray[$class['title']] ) ) {
    $presenters = explode( ', ', $newArray[$class['title']]['presenter'] );
    $presenters[] = $class['presenter'];
    $newArray[$class['title']]['presenter'] = implode( ', ', $presenters );

    $e = $newArray[$class['title']]['description'];
    $n = $class['description'];
    $newArray[$class['title']]['description'] = (strlen($n) > strlen($e) ? $n : $e);
  }
  else {
    $newArray[$class['title']] = $class;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works beautifuly with the additional of an addition parentheses in the if line.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many times a day I miss parens like that... edited now :-)